# AWS and spinning down an Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a test environment setup (along with a staging and production). The staging environment has spun down automatically in to red (health).

[image: spun down server]

I would like to spin down the test server as well, is this possible without destroying the actual instance? I will be using it again in a few months, but until then I don't need it consuming resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server == Instance.

Termination ==> killing a server, no chance to get it back.

Stop => Stopping a server, it can be restarted. No EC2 costs while it's stopped. ( EBS costs may apply.)

Having a single node Beanstalk environment means having 1 EC2 instance. I never tried to stop it, but you should be able to do it. ( Just check it a few minutes ago, if AWS spins up a new instance or not. In a single node setup it shouldn't.)

Comment: Where is the option to stop? I see `load configuration`, `save configuration`, ... `Restart App Servers`, `Rebuild Environment`, `Terminate Environment`

Comment: You are at the Elastic Beanstalk page. Go to the EC2 page -> instances. You should be able to find your instance launched by Beanstalk. Stop it.